# Why is hello_world not working in Ruby on Ubuntu?

Tags: ruby

My very first Ruby program: `hello_world.rb`:

```
puts ¨Hello World¨
```

I have saved it and when I try to run it from terminal, it returns:

```
ruby hello_world.rb
hello_world.rb:1:in `<main>': uninitialized constant World¨ (NameError)
```

I tried installing reinstalling ruby AND the editor(ATOM).  That is really all I could think of to try.  Any ideas would really help

-ruby 3.0.1p64.  Ubuntu

Comment: Please cut and paste your actual code. `puts "Hello World"` works fine, so either you didn't post your actual code or you're making some other error.

Comment: I would expect some sort of syntax error. Make sure you didn't accidentally get smart quotes, although atom will probably prevent that (sometimes it doesn't though). Try replacing the quotes manually.

Comment: Could be related to [Keyboard types diacritics (¨) instead of double quotes](https://superuser.com/q/518806/273967)

Answer (score 2):

Your string is not wrapped in double-quotes (`"`) but in [`¨`](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/%C2%A8) characters.

Replace

```
puts ¨Hello World¨
```

with

```
puts "Hello World"
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably copy as pasted `puts "Hello World"` from some website whose formatting changes the quotes. They are not valid quotes for strings. Retype the quotes yourself.

Comment: I typed them myself.  When I type in quotations, it always looks like that.  " .  I tried typing a quotation in all of my editors and they all behave the same way.

Comment: Could be the keyboard/language you are using. Make sure you are using the standard English language pack.